# How can compile a .c file with riscv-none-embed-gcc compiler and generate intruction code at every consecutive address?

Tags: compilation, riscv32

I have a question:
How ca I compile a .c file with riscv-none-embed-gcc and generate every instruction word at consecutive address (not at every 4 offset):
example:
0:   fe010113            addi    sp,sp,-32
4:   00812e23            sw  s0,28(sp)
8:   02010413            addi    s0,sp,32
c:   fe042623            sw  zero,-20(s0)
10:   fe042623            sw  zero,-20(s0)

to

0:   fe010113            addi    sp,sp,-32
1:   00812e23            sw  s0,28(sp)
2:   02010413            addi    s0,sp,32
3:   fe042623            sw  zero,-20(s0)
4:   fe042623            sw  zero,-20(s0)

thanks...

I'm trying to compile a .c source with gcc compile.